# Running 2 Powershell Scripts Sequentially

Tags: powershell

I have two Powershell scripts that work just fine separately, but I want to somehow combine them into one. The problem is that they rely on each other, meaning that the instructions in the first one must be completed in order for the second one to actually work. I do this with tons of files in different languages, but I'm just going to add part of the code here since it basically repeats itself for other languages.

First one I have simply changes the a bunch of files names to fix language ISO codes at once depending on a small part of their name:

```
Set-Location -PassThru
Get-ChildItem *.json  |Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '-pt-br','-pt_BR'} ; 
Get-ChildItem *.json  |Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '-es-es','-es_ES'} ; 
Get-ChildItem *.json  |Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '-es-mx','-es'} ;
```

So once this script does its trick, I run this other one to make changes to the actual content of the previous files (basically changing a tiny part of the code that says "en" into something else depending on the language of the file), but the selection of such files does depend on their names:

```
Set-Location -PassThru
(Get-Content *-pt_BR.json) |
  Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '"(en)"','"pt_BR"'}  |
    Out-File *-pt_BR.json 

(Get-Content *-es_ES.json) |
  Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '"(en)"','"es_ES"'}  |
    Out-File *-es_ES.json 

(Get-Content *-es.json) |
  Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '"(en)"','"es"'}  |
    Out-File *-es.json
```

By the way, I tried just placing these two scripts in the same file and running it does absolutely nothing, the script just deletes itself after running it and no changes are made to the files.

Also, **the -PassThru attribute is a must here since I need to have one .ps1 file that people can just copy paste into a folder and run**, otherwise it won't be compatible with the workflow.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: "the script just deletes itself" - not unless you put something else in there - please show the actual script that combines them

Comment: I just placed both codes in the same file, no additional changes, I know it seems odd since you should include something like Remove-Item -LiteralPath $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Force
for that to happen, but it does actually delete itself withouth any instructions to do so.

Comment: you can have one master script start the other scripts in sequence. powershell operates in sequence ... [*grin*]

Comment: But would that work with the -PassThru attribute though? I'm guessing I would need to paste 3 scripts (2 existing ones and the master script) into the corresponding folder and then run the master, because the location/path of the json won't always be the same

Comment: I don't get why `Set-Location -PassThru` is a must, you could simply use `$PSScriptRoot`

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on that @SantiagoSquarzon? I mentioned it was a must because I need people to be able to run the script simply by pasting it into their desired folder, but of course if there is another solution that does the same thing, it can go away

Comment: @GuillermoUmpierrez `Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot -Filter *.json |...`

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen, that does work, but it does the same as the -PassThru attribute, so it doesn't really fix my issue

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the code into one script, and instead of using `Set-Location` you can use the automatic variable `$PSScriptRoot` to determine the current location where the script is running.

Notice on part 2 i'm using `\(` & `\)` to escape the special characters, i'm not sure if your json files have `"(en)"` or `"en"`, you'll need to test and find out.

```
# Part 1
Get-ChildItem "$PSScriptRoot\*.json" | Rename-Item -NewName {
    switch -Regex($_)
    {
        '-pt-br'{$_.Name -replace '-pt-br','-pt_BR'}
        '-es-es'{$_.Name -replace '-es-es','-es_ES'}
        '-es-mx'{$_.Name -replace '-es-mx','-es'}
    }
}

# Part 2
Get-ChildItem "$PSScriptRoot\*.json" | ForEach-Object {
    switch -Wildcard($_)
    {
        '*-pt_BR.json'{
            (Get-Content $_) -replace '"\(en\)"','"pt_BR"' | Out-File $_.FullName
        }
        '*-es_ES.json'{
            (Get-Content $_) -replace '"\(en\)"','"es_ES"' | Out-File $_.FullName
        }
        '*-es.json'{
            (Get-Content $_) -replace '"\(en\)"','"es"' | Out-File $_.FullName
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, Santiago! Your solution works perfectly if I remove the "$PSScriptRoot" part and simply copypaste it on Powershell and run it manually using the Set-Location command to select my desired folder, but for some reason it will do absolutly nothing when I run the .ps1 file just as it is.

Comment: The script should work fine with `$PSScriptRoot` as long as the `.ps1` is in the same folder as the json files @GuillermoUmpierrez